# How to use background-postion to make responsive images

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am using Wordpress native menus for my custom theme. The catch is, that I am using background images instead of text. That being said: I have all of my images in tact but now I'm trying to make the images scale down responsive when the `.wrapper` container they are in scales down.

My latest attempt involves using `background-postion:` property and `background-size:` property and getting the image to scale with it's parent element. In this case the `.wrapper`. My overall goal is to get the images to stay in a horizontal line the width of the wrapper and scale down to size when the wrapper scales down.

```
    .wrapper {
        max-width:1280px;
        width:95%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

.nav ul li {
    float:left;
    max-width:100%;
    height:119px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
/* nav elements */


li#menu-item-1688 a {
    background:url('img/ksl_news.png'); 
    max-width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-position:center center;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}
```

I am looking for a pure css solution if possible.

Please let me know what other info you need in order to help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The images are not scaling down to size and staying horizontally inline. See edit.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking exactly. I notice that your `.wrapper` class takes 95% of it's parent element, which is `body`? In addition, nothing in your `li#menu-item-1688 a` indicates its ability to respond to width and height changes.

Comment: Do you mean the <li> element doesn't scale with the .wrapper? You have a width and height set on your <li>.

Comment: @AndrewManson the parent element is .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

Comment: I am trying make the <li>, which is an image, responsive and scale down in size when it's parent element scales down. In essence I have 9 "boxes" that are all the same width and height. I want those boxes to always stay in a horizontal row and shrink down when their surroundings shrink down so they can stay in line.

Comment: You have a fixed pixel value for the width and height of your <li>. You need to look there in order to scale that element.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by when `.wrapper` scales down. Do you mean when the width changes?

Comment: I have tried using max-height and max-width as well as percentages that contain the aspect ratio of the images and that doesn't do the trick.

Comment: When the size of the browser decreases width wise. @AndrewManson

Comment: I think I understand now, you are trying to make a responsive design based on the width and height of the actual browser window, not the screen resolution of the user. Correct?

Comment: That is correct! To be extra clear: I am trying to make a nav menu that consist of specific sized images stay in a horizontal row and scale down in size in order to do so when the browser scales down.@AndrewManson.

Comment: This would be easiest for you to search for resources on a jQuery based plugin that would add a class to your `body` based upon size of browser window. Unfortunately, you will not be able to create a website that scales down as a user changes the size of their browser, but you can set specific sizes that you want to change elements. For example, if the size of the window is less than 800 then add a `medium_window` class to body and then style your elements that way.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would to use simple jQuery to detect window/browser size changes and add classes to the necessary elements.

```
 var $window = $(window),
     $body = $('body');

 $(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($window.width() < 800) {
       $body.addClass('medWin');
   }else{
    $body.removeClass('medWin')};
 });
```

Then you would style:

```
body.medWin .menu li {
    // style here
}
```

You could also just apply the class to the menu container or the `ul` itself.

Comment: I am looking for a pure css route. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't do that if I were you, but of course it's up to you.

Comment: Why would I use javascript for something that can be done and is done all the time with css. I am just trying to get an image to scale with background-position:cover; or background-contain but it's just trickier because they are all in a row.

Comment: You have a specific size for your height for .nav ul li, to create a pure CSS responsive website you would have to specify percentages rather than actual values. I am still not exactly sure why you would be trying to accomplish this.